# Errors when calling data events REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, error, dataextensions

I am trying to call `/hub/v1/dataevents/key:MyKeyA/rowset` for 2 data extensions via Fiddler and I can't get either working.

MyKeyA is just a data extension. When I call the API, I get a 596 service not found error.

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:MyKeyA/rowset HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: auth.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer ___MY_TOKEN___

[] <-- 596 Service Not Found
```

MyKeyB is a data extension with a triggered email with OrderID as the primary key. When I call the API with MyKeyB, it "works" with an empty array, but gives me a 400 when I put any data in.

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:MyKeyB/rowset HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: auth.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer ___MY_TOKEN___

[] <-- 200 OK

POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:MyKeyB/rowset HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: auth.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer ___MY_TOKEN___

[{
    keys:{
        "OrderID": 123
    },
    values:{
        "EmailAddress": "MY_WORK_EMAIL",
        "SubscriberKey": "MY_WORK_EMAIL",
        "GrandTotal": 500,
        "InvoiceDate": "9/9/2015"
     }
}]
^-- 400 bad request **
```

** I use my work email for the email address.

Am I  missing something? I am trying to insert a new row with valid data.

**Update Nov 16, 2015**

I was able to get the first call working by wrapping all my names in quotes (all the properties including ET's keys and values). See below.

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:MyKeyB/rowset HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer ___MY_TOKEN___

[{
    "keys":{
        "OrderID": 123
    },
    "values":{
        "EmailAddress": "MY_WORK_EMAIL",
        "SubscriberKey": "MY_WORK_EMAIL",
        "GrandTotal": 500,
        "InvoiceDate": "9/9/2015"
     }
}]
```

The 596 error was because I accidentally used auth.exacttargetapis.com as my host (copy/paste error from my call to grab the token).

I now get a 202 and it puts the data in. Though if there is an error, it does not let me know.

Comment: When you say that you are trying to insert a blank row, what exactly do you mean by this? Do you want to insert a record with the order ID? Also, have you tried using the [putDataExtensionRowByKeyAsync](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/putDataExtensionRowByKeyAsync.html) method to insert a single DE? Does that work?

Comment: I've updated the original question: I meant a new row, no idea why I said blank. Yes, I want to insert a record with the Order ID. I get a 202 with the put method (I tried with an existing record and a new record).

Comment: This is the correct behavior. You will get a 202 status code (with an empty payload) if the response is correct. If there is an error, you should not receive a 2xx HTTP status code.